# como cambiar el parámetro de una lista con un boton en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy intentando hacer un script en el que al pulsar un boton un parametro de una lista booleana se actualize, pero con este codigo no pasa.

```py
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

array = [False, False, False, False, False, False]

def a():
    array[0] = True

def b():
    array[1] = True


a = Button(master, text = 'Button A', command = a)

b = Button(master, text = 'Button B', command = b))

a.pack()
b.pack()

print(array)

if array[0] and array[1] == 1:
    print(array)


master.mainloop()
```

Al pulsar el boton no cambia en el índice 0 False por True. No se que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te has dejado la comprobacion (el `if`) fuera de la interactividad del script. Pero en realidad tu script si que esta funcionando y cambiando el valor de los indices.

Si pruebas esto:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
array = [False, False, False, False, False, False]

def a():
    print('pressed A') # Nos sirve para chequear que efectivamente hemos apretado el boton
    array[0] = True
    print(array) # Vemos si efectivamente el array cambia
    if array[0] and array[1] == 1: # Comprobamos si ambos indices han cambiado
        print('Valores Cambiados!')

def b():
    print('pressed B')
    array[1] = True
    print(array)
    if array[0] and array[1] == 1:
        print('Valores Cambiados!')


a = Button(master, text = 'Button A', command = a)
b = Button(master, text = 'Button B', command = b)

a.pack()
b.pack()

# Esto no hace falta
# if array[0] and array[1] == 1:
#    print(array)

master.mainloop()
```

Si haces click en el Boton A y luego en el boton B, el output queda:

```
pressed A
[True, False, False, False, False, False]
pressed B
[True, True, False, False, False, False]
Valores Cambiados!
```